# Why are copying object doesn't affect the first object?

Tags: java, arrays, object, reference, copy

I am beginner at java, so I found something has made me confused:
Why when we create something like below:

```
String name = "Abdelillah";
String editName = name;
editName = "Mohammed";
```

My question is why the editName doesn't change name object?
But when we use arrays, if we create a reference to the first array, the second affect the first
I need to know why please and thank you

Comment: Because there's no link whatsoever between the variables `editName` and `name`, even when they happen to contain the same value (in this case, a reference to an object). `editName = name` just copies the value (an object reference, not the object itself) in `name` into `editName`. It's exactly the same reason that this doesn't change `a`:
`int a = 42;
int b = a;
b = 67;
System.out.println(a); // 42`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second line, `editName` is made to point to the same object as `name`. Both `name` and `editName` point to the string `"Abdelillah"`.

Your mistake may be in thinking that the third line changes the contents of the object that `editName` points to (`"Abdelillah"`). Rather, in the third  line,   `editName`  is made to point to a *different* object, the string `"Mohammed"`.